# Getting ViewModel Instance by ViewModelProvider

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

**ViewModelProviders is deprecated**

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::Class.java)
```

As suggested by other StackOverflow answers and This is not being found:

```
ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

There seems to be a problem with `onCleared()` not being called in:

```
ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory().create(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

Also, I don't want to use KTX-Extensions `by viewmodel()`

The last option is:

```
ViewModelProvider(this, myViewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

which needs a ViewModelFactory that I haven't figured how to implement and return the instance:

```
class ViewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        ...
    }

}
```

It's been a long time I've been injecting my ViewModels by using **Koin** and not using it makes it confusing to get an instance of a ViewModel.

**Is there any way to get an instance of ViewModel easily in API Level 30?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is completely gone from API 30

"API 30" refers to an Android SDK framework version. `ViewModelProviders` was never in the framework. `ViewModelProviders` still exists [in `lifecycle-extensions`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/lifecycle/lifecycle-extensions/2.2.0) and [is still documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders). You are correct that it is deprecated.

> This is also gone

No, it is not. It is available [in `lifecycle-viewmodel`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel/) and [is still documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider?hl=en#ViewModelProvider(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner)).

> Is there any way to get an instance of ViewModel easily in API Level 30?

Use `ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)` (your second code snippet). See [this Java example](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/blob/v0.9/ViewModel/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/samplerj/viewmodel/MainActivity.java#L37) (in Kotlin, I use a property delegate, either Google's or Koin's).

Comment: Yes, you're right. ViewModelProvider is inside the `ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)` dependancy.